# Apache accessing /media/ instead of DocumentRoot/media

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My Apache config has the following statements :

```
    DocumentRoot /home/x/public/
    <Location />
       Order Allow,Deny
       Allow from all
      Options -ExecCGI -Indexes
    </Location>
```

There is a directory /media under /home/x/public/

```
    RewriteRule ^(/media/.+) $1 [L]
```

Media files should be left untouched and served by Apache - other requests are redirected to a Ruby on Rails Proxy server.

Whenever I try to access a file under /media through a browser, Apache tries to serve /media/file (on the filestystem root dir) instead of /home/x/public/media/file

If I rename /media into /medias, the file /home/x/public/media/file is served correctly.

How can I prevent this behaviour ?

Edit : adding mod_rewrite logs :

If "mv /media/ /medias" :

```
applying pattern '^(/media/.+)' to uri '/media/css/TableTools.css'
rewrite '/media/css/TableTools.css' -> '/media/css/TableTools.css'
local path result: /media/css/TableTools.css
prefixed with document_root to /home/x/public/media/css/TableTools.css
go-ahead with /home/x/public/media/css/TableTools.css [OK]
```

If "mv /medias /media" :

```
applying pattern '^(/media/.+)' to uri '/media/css/TableTools.css'
rewrite '/media/css/TableTools.css' -> '/media/css/TableTools.css'
local path result: /media/css/TableTools.css
go-ahead with /media/css/TableTools.css [OK]
```

Comment: Adding         Alias /media /home/x/public/media does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the rewriterule to :

RewriteRule ^(/media/.+) /home/x/public/$1 [L]

Although ugly, it works.